# How to configure Ajenti V hosted website with extension less URL

Tags: nginx, php, extension

I am trying ways to configure my website to be extension less. That is when .*php* or .*html* files are visited, it'll be redirected to an URL without the extension.

```
Eg:
www.mywebsite.com/products.php will redirect to www.mywebsite.com/products
```

Anyone has successfully configured their **Ajenti V** with this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use Ajenti's own KB community [to ask this same question](http://support.ajenti.org/topic/474915-how-to-configure-ajenti-v-hosted-website-with-extension-less-url/) and was able to solve it. For everyone's ref, here's how: http://support.ajenti.org/topic/476525-hiding-php-extension/ . The instruction below is main step from that article.

Create an additional PHP type content entry with URL pattern set to / (root), and paste following into **Advanced > Custom Configuration** field:

```
try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/;
```